# From the F# interactive, why would it not accept this?

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I am using the F# CTP 1.9.7.8 and running the samples based on Tomas Petricek's article, on page 12

```
type MyCell(n:int) =
   let mutable data = n + 1
   do printf "Creating MyCell(%d)" n

   member x.Data
     with get() = data
     and  set(v) = data <- v

   member x.Print() =
     printf "Data %d" n

   override x.ToString() = 
     sprintf "(Data %d)" data

   static member FromInt(n) = 
     MyCell(n)
```

Four questions comes into mind as I typed this into the F# Interactive:

1. Why do I get an error message as shown below in Figure 1.
2. Why is there an `=` beside the `member x.Print()`, `x.ToString()` but not in `member x.Data`?
3. Where did the `x` come from? and why is it there when the type `MyCell` is being defined so how can you reference an 'object' in that way, such as for `x.Print()`, `x.ToString()` and `x.Data`?

```
> type MyCell(n:int) =
- let mutable data = n + 1

  type MyCell(n:int) =
  -----^^^^^^^

stdin(6,6): error FS0547: A type definition requires one or more members or othe
r declarations. If you intend to define an empty class, struct or interface, the
n use 'type ... = class end', 'interface end' or 'struct end'.
-
```

***Figure 1.***

Thanks,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. As pblassucci said, you need to indent your class's contents.
2. `Print` and `ToString` are methods, but `Data` is a property, so for `Data` the `=` comes before the definitions of the `get` and `set` methods.
3. Instead of always using an identifier like `this` to refer to the class whose members are being defined, F# lets you choose an identifier on a member-by-member basis.  `x` is used in many examples, but the choice is arbitrary.

Comment: @kvb: Cool! Thanks for that answer! :) +1 from me...short, simple and sweet! :)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like to:

```
> type MyCell(n:int) =
- let mutable data = n + 1
```

is not respecting the indentation. F# is whitespace sensitive by default, so you must keep any indentation. Try instead:

```
> type MyCell(n:int) =
-     let mutable data = n + 1
-     // etc.
```

(You can make F# non-whitespace sensitive by adding #light "off" at the top of the file, then you need to use extra keywords, as per danben's answer).

Comment: This is sometimes quite annoying - the fact that ">" in the F# interactive shell can sometimes break your indentation when pasting code! Fortunately, using Alt+Enter in VS works fine.

Answer (score 3):

even simpler, just indent your class body...

```
> type MyCell(n:int) =
-     let mutable data = n + 1
...
```